# How to use the liblinearutil package to train and predict test file in python?

Tags: python, nlp, liblinear

Can anyone give any insight about the liblinearutil package in python? I want to train and test files. I did read the documentation but don't quite understand. I'm doing it this way:

```
from liblinearutil import *
def testing_func(train_file, test_file)
    prob, param = svm_read_problem(train_file)
    m = liblinear.train(prob, param)
    print "m"
    print m
    p_labels, p_acc, p_vals = liblinear.predict(y,x, m, '-b 1')
    print (p_labels, p_acc, p_vals)
```

But, I'm getting "No module named liblinearutil error"! Could somebody please explain!!

Answer (score 0):

this error tell you that liblinearutil is not installed ;)
it's not available in pipy so you need to build from source for the good interpret (care if you have different python version installed)

Comment: How to know which interpreter I have? :/
I did :  import sys
>>> sys.executable
And got this: '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Resources/Python.app/Contents/MacOS/Python'

Comment: this is python 2.7. But forget this for the moment. Did you downloaded the module and installed it or not ? cause if not just install it :) if yes and it s not importable we will see

Comment: I downloaded it from here : http://www.csie.ntu.edu.tw/~cjlin/liblinear/
and in the README, it says to do 'make' to install, did that too. But, nothings happening. :/

Comment: I installed it and it works but all they give you is really the minimum, you don't have a setup.py, you don't even have a build target for install. So you need to type make in the main directory, then type make in the python directory. After that you can use the 2 python modules but only if you launch python in the same directory of the 2 modules. The standard way is to install python modules after built it. If you install python modules you will also need to put the shared lib on your system path

Comment: Hi @LindaSu, I ran into the same problem and I figured out how to properly install liblinearutil. Do you still need help?

Comment: @lollerskates hey, could you help me with it? I have the same problem and I am trying to figure it out. Thanks